# jQuery append() not working inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal as following:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="container-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="modal_containers" id="list_ctns">
         <li><img src="images/container.png"></li>
         <li><img src="images/container.png"></li>
         <li><img src="images/container.png"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above modal is triggered when a particular button is clicked which can be considered as a repository of certain elements.

I have a form which has a submit button. On clicking that submit button, I want to append a list item to the modal_body.

```
<div class="button-containers">
 <button class="btn btn-success" id="save_item" type="submit">Save</button>
</div>
```

So, I wrote this simple javascript snippet to append the list item to the modal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#save_item').click(function(e){
   $("#list_ctns").append("<li><img src="images/container.png"></li>")
});

});
```

[image: The current Modal]

I am not sure, where I am making a mistake. Please help me with your suggestions.

Cheers,
SZ

Comment: if your button is of type `submit` then its going to cause a `postback`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mind the quotes when you pass that as a string to set a value.

```
"<li><img src="images/container.png"></li>"
```

should be either

```
"<li><img src='images/container.png'></li>"
```

**or**

```
"<li><img src=\"images/container.png\"></li>"
```

Also don't forget to prevent the default action of the submit button.

```
$('#save_item').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#list_ctns").append("<li><img src='images/container.png'></li>")
});
```

Comment: Aaah. The quotes. Damn. Wonderful. I used the e.preventDefault();, I forgot to write that line in the script in the above question. But it is working great now. Thanks a lot @Sushanth. Such a stupid mistake and beautiful simple fix.

Comment: @ShellZero . Everyone gets carried over once in a while. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: I have a question. How can we add sequential numbering under those test tubes. If we use the <ol> - ordered list, the numbers would be on the side and they look ugly, is there a way to add the numbers on the bottom of the test tubes?

Comment: You don't need to introduce  another `ol` for that case. That can be done using some `CSS`. Just have a `span` or `div` element and give it a `position:absolute` and it's parent `li` a `position:relative` and set the left for the element accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The button type is submit so when you click it, the form will submit causing the page to be redirected to the "action" url.

You can create a JS function to handle it like this;

```
function handleModal(form)
{
    $("#list_ctns").append("<li><img src=\"images/container.png\"></li>");

    //Use $.AJAX() to submit the form without refreshing the page.

    return false; //this prevent the form from being submitted. Keep it if you are going to use $.AJAX() to submit the form or remove it if you want the form to submit normally.
}
```

and then call it from the `<form>` node by adding `onsubmit="return handleModal(this);"` attribute to it.